# Construct bijective functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We were given $f:[0,\infty) \to(0,\infty)$, and we were supposed to construct a bijective function from this. My teacher defined f as

$f(x) = \begin{cases} x+1 ~\text{if}~ x \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}\\x, ~\text{if otherwise}\end{cases}$

My question is if there is a certain trick or technique to construct bijective functions like this? or do you have to brute force it by checking surjectivity and injectivity constantly when constructing the function?

Comment: There's no single trick, but there are some common ones you should know, including this one.  You could call this the "Hilbert Hotel" trick.  If you know you can construct a bijection $\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, you can use this to construct bijections from any set $X \cup \{y\} \rightarrow X$ if $X$ is infinite.

Comment: Other common tricks for constructing bijections are, e.g., using $\arctan x$ to map a finite open interval to the entire real line; using prime factorization to map $\mathbb{N}$ to the direct sum $\oplus_{i =0}^\infty \mathbb{N}$ (map $p_1^{n_1} \cdots p_k ^{n_k} \rightarrow (n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k, 0, 0, \ldots)$; playing with binary expansions... if you know how to do enough of these common tricks you can string them together to get most of the bijections you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that if you take one point out of an infinite set the cardinality of the set does not change. As you notice the set  $$\{0,1,2,3,...\}$$ and$$ \{1,2,3,4,....\}$$ are in one-to-one correspondence with each other  via the function $ f(x)=x+1$ and the rest of the interval is mapped to itself by the identity map.

You can construct other bijective maps using the same trick and take away countably many points out of an  infinite set while the cardinality of the set does not change.

For example the two sets $$\{1,2,3,4,....\}$$ and $$\{1000,2000,3000,4000,.....\}$$ have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not a certain trick. Sometimes it is hard to find a bijective function, sometimes it is not.

Lets observe the sets that we are supposed to map onto each other.

$[0,\infty)$ and $(0,\infty)$.

The only difference in these sets is that $0$ is an element of the $[0,\infty)$, while it is not an element of $(0,\infty)$. 
So the first question we might ask is "What do we map 0 onto", because the sets are so similar that the first function that comes to mind might be the identity. But this does not work, since then $0$ has no image.

So we have to choose some element of $(0,\infty)$ to map $0$ onto. 
In your solution this element is $1$, which makes sense. It is then pretty normal to go on like that, and map 1 onto 2,2 onto 3 and so on.

Comment: So, by that you mean we have to try constructing a bijective function for the first interval, then a different bijective function for the second one? I ask this because I've been looking at the function as a whole instead of as two parts.

Comment: Maybe you can view it like that. If you observe your set $(0,\infty)=\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty (i,i+1)\cup \mathbb{N}$. Then what we are doing is basically to shift $\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}to\mathbb{N}$ like said in the accepted answer. But this is in my opinion a more complicated viewpoint. As I said, the question we have to ask is what $0$ gets mapped on. That is the real problem. If we do that we destroy something, because when we map $0\mapsto 1$, then we have to make sure not an other element gets mapped onto $1$ and so on. Taking natural numbers, is natural, because it is most easy to 'undrstnd'